# Are there any dangers in Lombok that I should know about before?

Tags: international-travel, indonesia, lombok

Hello I will fly to Lombok at the end of March for 2 weeks. Are there any dangers (diseases, pickpockets or similar) that I should know about?

Comment: I edited that part out, since it's too broad to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alcohol**

Apparently you should be aware of alcohol as some die beachside of methanol poisoning.

From [smarter travel:](https://www.smartertravel.com/tips-lombok-warnings-dangers-stay-safe/)

> Beware of the alcohol in Indonesia! Several people have died in the last years from methanol-poisoning! DO NOT buy ANY COCKTAILS! And DO NOT buy ANY alcohol in the stores. They mix or make the alcohol diluted with methanol. It is extremely DANGEROUS!  BEWARE! Most deaths have been in Bali, Lombok and Gili Island, especially Gili

**Currents**

If you do decide to go swimming beware as there are very strong currents:

> While the blissfully clear, turquoise water may seem as safe as a bathtub, be warned that there are very strong currents flowing between the islands and underestimating their power can be and have been fatal.

**Harbour**

If you’re driving a boat some may flood it an try to steal suitcases.

> Be aware of the porters that will flood (mob) your boat when arriving. We were “attacked” by 5 really scruffy men fighting over our suitcases. We tried to get them away as we could handle our luggage ourselves. They wouldn’t listen.

**Drugs**

Drugs are freely available in public even though there are strict laws.

> When in Gili Trawangan, people seem to be offering all sorts of drugs in public. We even got asked by a waiter who took our order at a restaurant if we wanted some magic mushrooms. I think this is mainly due to no police on the island.

**Crime**

Because of the lack of police you should take care with your belongings.

Some suggestions:

> Make sure that all your valuables are locked safely away at your accommodation. Ask at your lodgings for a safety deposit box but don’t be surprised if they don’t have any, especially at the cheaper accommodation. When you are out ensure your bags are locked and chained if possible and that the doors and windows are secure. Most theft is opportunistic and taking sensible precautions will eliminate the risk of petty crime. Also avoid walking alone at night around isolated parts of the islands including the western coasts and interior.

Comment: For the "Harbour" section I took "flood" to mean "flood the boat with water" as in "sink".  It took me a while to realize that the meaning was "mob"

Comment: @PeterM oh, i will add that in brackets

Comment: Not sure the drugs thing applies to Lombok, just the Gilis. I recall that while on Gili Air there were clearly sign posted "magic mushroom cocktails" on offer -- but Lombok mainland not at all.